# Android - onDraw not being called in dynamically inserted custom view

Tags: android, custom-view, ondraw

I have a custom view being dynamically inserted and the `onDraw` is not being called.  I initially made the custom view without the dynamic insertion and it worked fine, however when moving it to my working code base, I cannot get `onDraw` to get called ever, even though the view constructor gets called and the `onMeasure` also gets called.  I've tried putting `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate()` calls around the place, but they don't seem to force the view to draw.  The view hierarchy looks the same for both version and I'm lost.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:  A bit more testing has shown that `onDraw` is getting called on the emulator, but not the handset.  Also `onSizeChanged` on the handset has the correct values coming through, but on the emulator the values are all 0.

EDIT:  I've been playing about with it and still can't get anywhere, so have put a bounty on it.  If you need more code / xml / info then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the `View` to a `TextView` and it seems to work now, although I'm a little confused as to *why* the `View` didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a problem i had recently, with my first custom view. Did you notice if, when loading view hierarchy, your custom views show up? and anyway do they appear laid out in the wireframe preview or not?

If the latter is the case, it's `requestLayout()` that doesn't get called (loading view hierarchy calls that on every view - that's why it makes views show up). i've also found that a similar bug was reported already [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6089).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the views don't show in the hierarchy viewer and when requestLayout is overridden with a log statement, it's certainly getting called.  Actually, testing on the emulator - onDraw is getting called now, but the canvas has dimensions of the full screen, not just the view.